# I am unable to fetch information from MongoDB in the server component(Next JS 13) in production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, vercel

I am working on a small pet project using Next.js 13 (specifically version 13.4.1), and I have encountered a problem. I have a page, located at the following path (D:\Front-end\Next.js\football_next\src\app\dashboard\page.tsx), where two components are displayed: a list of posts created by the user and a form for creating new posts. The component responsible for the post list is a server component, in which I make a request to the MongoDB database and sort the retrieved results by user. Everything works fine in development mode; I can fetch the list and update it. However, when I execute the command npm run build followed by npm start, I encounter an error.

error: an error occurred in the server components render. the specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. a digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.

To troubleshoot, I tried converting the component responsible for the list into a client-side component, and in that case, no errors occur.

Is there a way to accomplish this in the server component after all?

this is my code snippets

```
this is my page.tsx

import React from "react";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import NewsForm from "../components/createPost/NewsForm";
import Card from "../components/PostsCreatedByUser/Card";

export default async function DashboardPage() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  if (!session) {
    redirect("/");
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8">
      <Card />
      <NewsForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
this is news list compponent

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Post } from "../../../../types/PostsType";
import getNews from "../../../../lib/getNewsFromDb";

export default async function Card() {
const data: Post[] = await getNews();

  const posts: Post[] = data.filter((el) => el.username === "Богдан Піщак");

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <img src={post.img} alt="img" width={200} height={200} />
            <p>{post.description}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
my fetch func 

export default async function getNews() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/getposts`, {
    method: "GET",
  });

  if (!res.ok) return undefined;

  return res.json();
}
```

```
my api route 
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import connect from "../../../../util/mongoConnect";
import Post from "@/models/Post";

export const GET = async (request: Request) => {
  try {
    await connect();

    const posts = await Post.find();
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(posts), { status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    return new NextResponse("Database Error", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

```
connection to DB
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI as any);
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Connection failed!");
  }
};

export default connect;
```